# LINQ, GroupBy inner value of field which has type of object

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to group collection by inner property value? how would I do this without creating a new object using only Linq. Or I need to create anonymous object before grouping process.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<ItemInv> Inventory {get; set;}
}

public class ItemInv
{
   public int wid {get; set;}
}

var lst = new List<Item> {
    new Item {
        Id=1,
        Inventory= new List<ItemInv> { new ItemInv() { wid = 2 } }
    },
    new Item {
        Id=2,
        Inventory= new List<ItemInv> { new ItemInv() { wid = 2 }}
    }
};
```

I need group this lst variable by **wid** property.

Comment: But how do you expect to group `Items` that have more than one `ItemInv`?

Comment: one object in different groups by wid field

Comment: Can there be duplicate `wid` values inside the same `Inventory` list? Note: you can't do this without some intermediate step because you need to "duplicate" objects (well, references to objects) once for each item in the `Inventory` list.

Comment: Yes. I'm agree. Thnx.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have almost the same solution as Gilad Green, but in method syntax.

```
var itemsByWid = lst
   .SelectMany(item => item.Inventory.Select(itemInv => Tuple.Create(itemInv, item)))
   .GroupBy(itemTuple => itemTuple.Item1.wid, itemTuple => itemTuple.Item2);
```

Comment: `z`, `y`, and `x` are *terrible* variable names.

Comment: @ErikE Agreed, that was pretty lazy. Edited.

Comment: For what it's worth, `Tuple` looks like it's not a value type, and so there could be some performance value in using `KeyValuePair` instead, as each one can then be allocated on the stack instead of the heap.

Answer (score 1):

To group the `Item`s by the `ItemInv`s with in their collections, first flatten the nested collections and then group by the `ItemInv`s:

```
var result = (from item in list
              from inv in item.Inventory
              group item by inv.wid into invGrouping
              select new {
                  ItemInv = invGrouping.Key,
                  Items = invGrouping.ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

For testing:

```
// Testing data
var list = new List<Item> {
    new Item {
        Id=1,
        Inventory= new List<ItemInv> { new ItemInv() { wid = 2 } }
    },
    new Item {
        Id=2,
        Inventory= new List<ItemInv> {
            new ItemInv() { wid = 2 },
            new ItemInv() { wid = 3 } }
    },
    new Item {
        Id=3,
        Inventory= new List<ItemInv> {
            new ItemInv() { wid = 3 } }
    } };

//Output: 
//    wid 2 - Item id=1, Item id = 2
//    wid 3 - Item id=2, Item id = 3
```

See that currently the grouping is by the `inv.wid`. If you desire grouping by the `ItemInv` instance you must first override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.